# How to code table of persons with their details in html5

Tags: html, html-table

I have following data for some people:

```
Name and surname | Category | Expiration date | +

----------

Sport            | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Base             | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Beginning date   | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

etc...
```

Anyway, it should look something like this:
http://www.hoo.hr/kategorizacija.aspx?sportid=32&katid=I&olimpid=3&zupanijaid=0

Just click plus sign on the right side of the table and info about certain athlete will pop up (give it a little time, its an old script)

This is currently made in a way that ajax loads additional data from database and then inserts a new tr element which contains table element (e.g. `<tr><td><table>...</table></td></tr>`).

This is not nice markup and is not searchable by search engines. Is there a better way to achieve this maybe by using description list? (I won't use ajax but rather load additional data for all athletes in one go)

Answer (score 0):

The first question is, if you want to build the grid on the clientside (html, javascript), or on the serverside (C#, Java, PHP, or something similar). If you want to build it on the clientside you will need an ajax call so or so, even if you want to load all data at once.

The next question is, how big is the amount of data you would have in the full list and how much performance it costs you to load the dataset. 
There are different ways you can possibly go. You can do it as it is and load only the data that are actual viewable in the grid, you can do it like you have it in mind and load the full dataset and you can also load a certain amount of data (for example the first 200 rows) and give the option to load more data when needed.

If you want to optimize the grid-data itself for search engines, then you must build the grid server side, because then the data are directly rendered out when the crawler retrieves the page. But that also only works out for the search engine when you directly display all existing data, without pagination.

For your point of not nice markup, in my opinion a table is the best solution for building a data grid, but it is not needed to have nested tables. you can achieve the same with with a hidden row that carries the detail data in a div.

So, all in all it is all a question of your exact use case and only you can make a decision what is the best way to retrieve the data and build the grid.

Comment: I said I want to build grid serverside (I want to pass all the data in one go) but I'm unsure about what markup for this kind of layout to use.

Tables are very unpractical and non semantic for this kind of layout and relation between data is not clearly visible to the search engine.

Comment: Let's face it, a data grid is nothing else than a table with some additional functions like sorting, filtering and pagination. What you do in a data grid is displaying table data (or how are they organized in your data source?) in a user friendly layout. I don't see a problem to use a table for displaying table data. And also search engines have no problems with tables, when build right. Only because you should not use tables for the page layout doesn't mean don't use tables for what they are made for.

Comment: If I enter aditional data as new row, there will be nothing that connects that data with "person" in the row above.

Comment: When you want to create your own custom data grid it is your task to make that relation between the first row and the second row. In the example you have given the connection is made clear to the user by the + icon in the first row, that open the second row.

Comment: Connection is obvious to living person, but not to search engine. That's what is bothering me.

Comment: When the search engine optimization is that important for the grid itself (that means you display the full data set at once without pagination and have no details hidden, or it is not optimized) then you can put the general data in one table row. in that table row you put a wrapper div. In that div you render at first the general data and under that you insert an inner div that holds the detail data.